# Onscreen image recognition for Linux

Tags: linux, open-source, computer-vision, image-recognition

I am looking for an open source program to recognise known features, letters, numbers and symbols, displayed on my screen on a 2D plane.

There may be some occlusion or particle effects over the images.

In this particular case I am trying to detect features from *Hearthstone* (an online card game).

The best answer will answer the question for a general case matching the features I am trying to identify as I want to develop with this and use it for other similar games.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux/Mac, I use Sikuli. It automates anything you see on the screen. It uses image recognition to identify and control GUI components. It is useful when there is no easy access to a GUI's internal or source code.

http://www.sikuli.org/

Sikuli is a JAVA app and cross-platform (Win, Mac, Linux).

Comment: Perfect, source for the original project here: https://github.com/sikuli/sikuli
Newer version here: https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX-2014
For the OCR engine behind it here: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract